# using python selenium not able to locate a text which is displayed in the browser

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a webpage which has two frames titlebar(source=navbar.html)and mainframe(source=mainpage.html). Initially switching to titlebar frame , identifying the textbox and submitting the values . After submission it redirects to new page targetted in mainframe (Now mainframe has archivedata.php). Now if I try to switch to mainframe , it throws the below error

driver.frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//frame[@name="mainframe"]')
*** selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//frame[@name="mainframe"]"}

so added the below line to the code

```
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

Now i could able to switch to the mainframe, but if I print the page source it displays the content of the mainpage.html which was present in the mainframe when the page was loaded initially before the form submission. I need to validate a text present in the source of archivedata.php which is displayed in the browser after the form submission. But using python selenium not able to get to the source of archivedata.php

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import re
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('ignore-certificate-errors')
testcase_list= ['1111']
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver',chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://xxxx.php")
search_bar = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
search_bar.clear()
search_bar.send_keys("xxxxx")
search_bar = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
search_bar.clear()
search_bar.send_keys("xxxxxx")
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(10)
frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//frame[@name="titlebar"]')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
search_bar = driver.find_element_by_name("targetTestCase")
search_bar.clear()
for case_id in testcase_list:
    search_bar.send_keys(case_id)
    search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    driver.switch_to_default_content()
    frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//frame[@name="mainframe"]')
    driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
    src = driver.page_source
    text_found = re.search(r'Scripted', src)
    print(src)
    if text_found:
        print("Present")
    else:
        print("not present")
```

Answer (score 0):

page_source is not a very reliable method to get HTML for very much issue you are facing right now. As it does not guarantee that it will return the current state of the page. A much better and reliable way is to use  JavaScript to get outerHTML.

```
src = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
text_found = re.search(r'Scripted', src)
print(src)
```